# How to :Retrieve & check nested Objects in an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested, javascript-objects

I have the following issue that I was not able to solve for the last couple of days.

So I have a class called "Nodes" which has the property Neighbors - which is an Array.

When  I insert into a Node (Node A) a  Node(Node B)  as a "Neighbor" into the Neighbors array, it has to be an instance of the Class Neighbors that takes the instance of Node B as a parameter as an "opposite node".

Now I have to create a Statement that checks if this connection between Node A and B already exists or not

what is the best way to do that? I came across the method of destructuring but I am not sure if that is suited for the task.

```
class Node {
  constructor(nodeName) {
    this.nodeName = nodeName;
    this.neighbours = [];
  }
};

class Neighbour {
  constructor(oppositeNode, weight = null) {
    this.oppositeNode = oppositeNode;
    this.weight = weight;
  }
};

nodea = new Node(a);
nodeb = new Node(b);
nodea.neighbours.push(new Neighbour(nodeb));
```

So the Statement that I want to be able to write is the following:

Pseudo Code

If (NODE A has NODE B in NODE A.neighbours) {x}

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a continuation of your script with a check using the `find` method:

```js
class Node {
  constructor(nodeName) {
    this.nodeName = nodeName;
    this.neighbours = [];
  }
};

class Neighbour {
  constructor(oppositeNode, weight = null) {
    this.oppositeNode = oppositeNode;
    this.weight = weight;
  }
};

nodea = new Node("a");
nodeb = new Node("b");
nodea.neighbours.push(new Neighbour(nodeb));

let neighbour = nodea.neighbours.find(neighbour => neighbour.oppositeNode == nodeb);

if (neighbour) console.log("found neighbor. It has weight " + neighbour.weight);
else console.log("not found");
```

Comment: Awesome thank you so much :) also tried the array.find method but messed up the last part ^^ Good thing that i was at least close ^^